# Have an excel cell value list except when the value is null

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I have an integer list "myList" that corresponds to empty excel lines and I would like to retrieve the values ​​of all cells that are not empty thanks to LINQ
I already dit that to get all the value:

```
 var colonneB = selectedRange.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().Select(x => x.Value2.ToString()).ToList();
```

and i tried that to get all the value without the empty cell:

```
 var colonneB = selectedRange.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().Select(x => x.Value2.ToString().Where(p => { x.Row != ctrl.myList.ElementAt(p); })).ToList();
```

and that :

```
var colonneB = selectedRange.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().Where(y => ctrl.myList.ForEach(p =>
            {
                int i = ctrl.myList.ElementAt(p);
                if (i != y.Row)
                {
                }
            }) != y.Row).Select(x => x.Value2.ToString()).ToList();
```

but of course it doesn't compile, I have tried other things but it doesn't work either and I am short of ideas...
Thank you for your help.

all the code :

```
 int nInLastRow = worksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Row;
 Excel.Range selectedRange = (Excel.Range)worksheet.get_Range("B2:B" + nInLastRow);
 var colonneB = selectedRange.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().Select(x => x.Value2.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: the last two do not compile

Comment: don't you need a ")" before ".Where" at the 2nd code sample? aka .Select(...).Where(...)

Comment: Could you put up a more complete piece of sample code please?

Comment: I did it @peteski22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well well well, I finally found the answer by myself (and i'm proud of me^^)
It was simple, just have to do :

```
var colonneB = selectedRange.Rows.Cast<Excel.Range>().Where(y=>y.Value2 != null).Select(x => x.Value2.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice, last time I players with Excel lambda's and LINQ didn't exist so was going to a have a play with it but great to see you've resolved it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<double> list = selection.Cast<Range>().Select(r => r.Value).OfType<double>().ToList();
```

to get all numbers, but faster to get all values at once:

```
object o = selection.Value;
List<double> list = (o as object[,] ?? new[,] { { o } }).OfType<double>().ToList();
```